# Diango can't be installed through pip.

Tags: python, web-services, pip

My python `version is 3.6.1` and my pip `version is 9.0.1`. My os is `centos 7.3`. When i run the command

> pip install diango

, the diango can't be installed. The error message is :

```
Collecting diango
  Using cached diango-1.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/diango.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info/diango.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/diango.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/diango.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/diango.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info/diango.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/diango.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-e3zbahes/diango/setup.py", line 21, in <module>
        urlopen('http://94.140.120.197/counter/diango.html')
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
        return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 532, in open
        response = meth(req, response)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 642, in http_response
        'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 570, in error
        return self._call_chain(*args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
        raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-e3zbahes/diango/
```

I think `urlopen('http://94.140.120.197/counter/diango.html')` may be the main problem so i copy the url into chrome. Unfortunately, this address is `"The requested URL /counter/diango.html was not found on this server."`. I do not know it is a bug or something else. Thanks any advice!

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you don't have setuptools installed?

Maybe try this:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Then try to install django with pip again.

Comment: I tried this. It says `Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in ./lib/python3.6/site-packages`.

Comment: ok cool, try `pip install ez_setup` and just double check your virtualenv is active (been caught out myself a few times with that!)

Comment: I am sure my virtualenv is active. I successfully installed ez_setup. It still show the same problems described above.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i successfully install diango through command

> pip install diango==1.11.2

Diango official group declare they have fixed the bug.